# police entering ... is illegal

Tags: possessives, gerund-clauses

Is the apostrophe "s" necessary in the following?

> Police('s) entering a private house without a warrant is illegal.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you trying to make *police* plural or possessive? If the latter, possessive of what? And you should add why you considered adding the apostrophe "s".

Comment: @user3169 If you read any books on English style and usage, you will know why the apostrophe "s" is considered.

Comment: OK, but it would be better if you put your reasoning in your question, just for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The possessive is not really used in such constructions by most speakers. Many books on style and usage insist on it, however:

> His entering the house in the wee hours of the morning gave them a start.

Many speakers would say **Him entering ...**.

The sentence as a whole is one many native speakers would avoid. They'd take one of the following approaches instead:

> It is illegal for the police to enter a private house without a warrant.
>
> For the police to enter a private house is illegal.

But you might hear or read something like this:

> Police entering a private house with a battering ram is a common sight in movies about drug busts.

There, **entering a private house with a battering ram** is a participial clause post-modifier of "police".

Comment: In your last example, the singular verb _is_ seems to indicate the subject is the event of entering a private house with a battering ram. The noun _police_ would require a plural verb.

Comment: @Apollyon:   You're not trying to suggest that  **entering** is the subject, are you?  The *sight* of police entering a private house with a battering ram is common in movies about drug busts.

Comment: If _entering a private house with a battering ram_ is a postmodifier of _police_ , then the main-clause verb should be plural, as the noun _police_ takes a plural verb.  _Police entering a private house with a battering ram are  typically issued with a warrant._

Comment: @Apollyon. Your reasoning is flawed in that it does not take into account the fact that the verb often agrees in number with a *semantic* subject, not the grammatical subject. The semantic subject here is expressed in the second half of the copula, *a common sight*.

Comment: Is it grammatical to say _Plain-clothes police officers is a common sight in Hollywood movies_ ?

Comment: Police officers dressed in plain clothes *are* meant to be mistaken for civilians.

Comment: If the speaker is presenting an image of police bashing a door in, the noun-phrase **police entering a private house with a battering ram** can serve as a singular subject. If the speaker is presenting multiple individual plainclothes policemen, it could be **Police officers dressed in plain clothes are a common sight ...**   If the speaker is envisioning a group:  Police officers all dressed in blue is a common sight in movies.